# NX React - how to create default mock for library

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, nrwl, nomachine-nx

How do you create manual mock for your libs, which are used by your apps?

I'm trying to follow scope mocking in [jest documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-node-modules) but have no luck.

#### Example:

```
my-workspace
├── __mocks__
│   └── @my-workspace/my-lib.ts
├── apps
│   ├── my-app
│       └── index.ts
├── libs
│   ├── my-lib
│       └── index.ts
...
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`libs` in an nx workspace can be imported like regular node_modules thanks to its [TS path mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) (check your `tsconfig.base.json` to see how `@workspace-scope/my-lib` is being resolved).

However, your lib is not a node module per say (even if you publish it), and should be mocked using the "user modules" jest pattern instead: https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks#mocking-user-modules

Move the mock to `libs/my-lib/__mocks__/index.ts` instead (you can split mocks into several files if you need, just make sure to export whatever you need to mock from the index file) then call `jest.mock('@workspace-scope/my-lib');` manually in the `spec` file where you import your lib function:

```
// libs/my-lib/__mocks__/index.ts
export function foo(): string {
  return 'foo';
}
```

```
// apps/my-app/.../some-test.spec.ts
import { foo } from '@workspace-scope/my-lib';

// manually mock the user module: make sure the path matches the import above
jest.mock('@workspace-scope/mylib');
// --> now when you invoke foo() in this file, jest should invoke "foo" exported from "libs/my-lib/__mocks__/index.ts" instead

describe('test foo', () => {
  test('returns "foo"', () => {
    expect(foo()).toBe('foo');
  });
});
```

Comment: The answer didn't work for me, but I changed the place of the `__mocks__` folder to be under `src` folder inside the library and it worked. Also one important note is that the call `jest.mock('@workspace-scope/mylib');` has to be at the top level (outside of `describe`).

Comment: Yes @Envil, also worked for me under the src folder.
In the jest documentation it says we should do mockClear(), do you guys think we need to clear something? I tried doing jest.clearAllMocks() but then the mock doesn't work :/